# How to solve No module named 'email.MIMEMultipart', when I have tried installing easy_install email?

Tags: python, mime-mail

> This is the simple email sending code I have copied from a source and trying to learn it. But this is giving error even after I have installed easy_install email. Below is the code :

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
def sendmail (from_email, password, to_email, subject, message):
    msg=MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From']= from_email
    msg['To']= to_email
    msg['Subject']= subject

    msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))
    try:
        server= smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.office365.com', 465)
        server.echo()
        server.login(from_email, password)
        server.sendmail(from_email, to_email, msg.as_string())
        server.close()
        return  True
    except Exception as e:
        print('Something went wrong '+str())
        return False
```

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\RYadav\PycharmProjects\MAPILab\rough work.py", line 1, in <module>
    import smtplib
  File "C:\Users\RYadav\PycharmProjects\MAPILab\smtplib.py", line 2, in <module>
    from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'email.MIMEMultipart'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: The correct import statement is `from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart`.  It's part of the email package in the standard library, you don't need to install anything extra.

Comment: @snakecharmerb, can't figure out if this is not the same import, where it's wrong?

Comment: The problem is in `"C:\Users\RYadav\PycharmProjects\MAPILab\smtplib.py"` (which has a name that clashes with the core `smtplib.py` - is it your file or a third party's?)

Comment: What a silly mistake I did. Yes it worked after removing that . Thanks 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this command :

---

from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

from email.mime.text import MIMEText

---

check this lien = https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.mime.html#module-email.mime

Comment: english only, please